# Error when getting the elements of a vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a function which takes in a string and puts the elements of the string into a vector with the only condition that repeated consecutive elements are ommitted, for example: "AABBC" -> ['A', 'B', 'C'].  My code is the following

```
std::vector<char> uniqueInOrder(const std::string& iterable){
    std::vector<char> result;
    for(int i = 0; i <= iterable.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(i==0 || result[i-1] != iterable[i]){
            result.push_back(iterable[i]);
        }else{continue;}

    }
    return result;

}
int main(){
    auto result  = uniqueInOrder("AABBC");
    for(auto val: result){std::cout << val  <<"\n";}
    return 0;
}
```

The expected ouptut of the function is: ['A', 'B', 'C']
The actual output is:  ['A', 'B', B', 'C']
I can't see why it wouldn't work. Apparently when in the if statement I get the result[i] element it gets "nothing" when there should be already an element inside.

Comment: `<=` should be strictly `<` (won't fix your issue though)

Comment: `result.back()` is the last element in the array. Compare *that* against `iterable[i]`. If you use `result[i-1]` you are trusting that every insertion until now has succeeded, which is not the case for eg "AAAABBBBBBBBC".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an additional solution I would like to offer a "more-modern" C++ approach with algorithms.

Theh your task can be basically done with a one liner and a Lambda.

We use an algorithm from the STL: `std::copy_if`. So, we will copy data from the string to the vector, but only if, the current character is different from the previous.

With taht, everything will be reduced to one statement.

```
int main() {

    // The source string
    std::string s{ "1133310133778" };

    // The desitnation vector
    std::vector<char> v{};

    // One liner to do the copying
    std::copy_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(v), [last = 0](const char c) mutable { bool retval{ true }; if (last == c)  retval = false; last = c; return retval; });

    // Debug output
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

And since nobody can read this on long line, I will insert some new lines for easier reading:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    // The source string
    std::string s{ "1133310133778" };

    // The desitnation vector
    std::vector<char> v{};

    // One statement to do the copying
    std::copy_if(
        s.begin(), 
        s.end(), 
        std::back_inserter(v), 
        [last = 0](const char c) mutable { 
            bool retval{ true }; 
            if (last == c)  
                retval = false; 
            last = c; 
            return retval; 
        }
    );

    // Debug output
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

This is the same as befor, just more new-lines.

Answer (score 1):

Your index into the result is wrong. `i` is the index into `iterable`, but you're using `i - 1` as an index into `result`. When you get to the fourth iteration of the loop, you look at `result[2]` (the third element of `result`), but result only has 2 elements; `{'A', 'B'}`, so you get nothing useful (undefined behaviour) and certainly not `'B'` as you expect.

Replace `result[i-1]` with `result.back()` so that it always reads the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Stu offers one solution. The other choice is to compare against iterable[i-1].

This line:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= iterable.size(); ++i)
```

The comparison should be < iterable.size(). This is going to to past the length of the array.

```
else{continue;}
```

This is entirely unnecessary.

This part:

```
    if(i==0 || result[i-1] != iterable[i]){
```

Could be:

```
    if(i==0 || iterable[i-1] != iterable[i]){
```

Answer (score 0):

First let your string be passed to vector as it is.
 Now use  STL feature [unique](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdunique-in-cpp/) to delete repetitive consecutive elements in your vector.

Also, you can directly apply this feature to your [String](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdunique-in-cpp/).